# Bitmap: Decoded image width and height returns -1

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have written this code to assist me on working on a bitmap, to improve the quality of the bitmap after resizing the image.
My problem is that the decoded bitmap returns -1 for both width and height and as a result the image never gets decoded to the output stream. This is the code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File (this.imageFileUri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);

            int srcWidth = options.outWidth;
            int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
            System.out.println("The image width is>>>>>> " +  srcWidth + "The image height is >>>>>>" + srcHeight);
            int scale = 1;
            int desiredWidth = 10;
            while(srcWidth / 2 < desiredWidth){
               srcWidth /= 2;
               srcHeight /= 2;
               scale *= 2;
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            this.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file1.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

Please where is my mistake and how can I avoid this.
Kindly assist!

Comment: Though its not a direct solution... But for image resizing i would recommend to use thumbnailator api... Its pretty great

Comment: Looks like you are decoding two different files, imageFileUri.getPath() and file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: @m vai: am trying to get the perfect resolution of a cropped image using bitmap factory options

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile();
```

This method returns a decoded Bitmap image (you can check the Bitmap documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html )

Try saving it like this:

```
Bitmap yourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(..,..);
```

Then to acces the width and height:

```
yourBitmap.getWidth(); // returns int
yourBitmap.getheight(); //returns int
```

Comment: The solution is to use a bitmap factory options method as I am saving it to a temporary storage. Actually tried the above approach before now but didnt work

Comment: I suppose it's something to do with the file, because checking the documentation it says:

outHeight will be set to -1 if there is an error trying to decode.

Why not try to set the file outside of the method so you have full controll over it.

Edit:

Or try not to create any file. Just pass the "this.imageFileUri.getPath()" directly as a first argument to the method.